# Wordpress - make background image cover 100% viewport height

Tags: css, wordpress

I am making a full page parallax image header for a wordpress blog. I have applied the following styles to the header image (I found out the css classes by inspecting it in dev tools).

```
.header {
    background: no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position:relative;
}
```

Even after applying this images, I notice a hige white space below the image, once I scroll it down. You can see the issue here: http://bakemachine.com/travel/

How can I remove this issue? I am using the Hemingway theme and am new to wordpress development. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fine here Chrome version 58, this is how parallax suppose to work

Comment: After scrolling down the parallax, there is a white gap between the image and the navigation. I inspected it, its the image content. I want to remoce that white gap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the gap bellow the image, just rewrite the `margin` rule on the `.section-inner`. This class is inside the navigation.

```
.section-inner {
    width: 1040px;
    max-width: 86%;
    margin: 0 auto; // this rule is changed
}
```